# GraphQL mutation on id field

Tags: graphql, graphiql

I have a GraphQL schema called *Car Manufacturer* which has two fields, `id` and `name`. What I am trying to accomplish via GraphiQL is to insert several data into the schema but I need to mutate both the mentioned fields.

Is there a way to insert a desired value on the `id` field?

Comment: You could create a mutation, something like `addManufacturer(id: ID!, name: string!)` to your schema. Then you can do `mutation` queries.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to modify the `id`? For using them as indexes? Like `id: 1`, `id: 2` an so on? If is that so, you should have something like `globalIdField` from `graphql-relay` in my opinion. Not mutate these `ids` yourself.
For example:

```
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLFloat } from 'graphql';
import { globalIdField } from 'graphql-relay';

export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Car anufacturer',
  description: 'desc',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('CarManufacturer'),
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: async obj => obj.title,
    },
  }),
});
```

This way you will have unique ids and you can turn these ids on an `ObjectId`for use with `MongoDB` for example.

If you want to change this values for whatever other reason, you have to create `Mutations` just like @arian said

I hope that I helped you someway :)

Comment: The reason that i want to modify the ids is because I am transferring data from a project to which the ids are being used.